# Elohim - Female Image of G-d

Tags: women, torah-study, theology, parashat-bereishit, men-male

There is a group that teaches that analyzing the words in Genesis 1:26 :

> 1. And God said, "Let us make man in our image, after our likeness, and they shall rule over the fish of the sea and over the fowl of the
>      heaven and over the animals and over all the earth and over all the
>      creeping things that creep upon the earth."
> 2. And God created man in His image; in the image of God He created him; male and female He created them.

The reason why two images came out, one male and one female, is because G-d has two images, a male and a female image, and that Elohim represents that. Here is a video where they explain it better :http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RdGiwk5ohNQ . How true is that? Is it possible for Elohim to mean that G-d has two images, a male and a female image? Thanks!

Comment: The group that teaches this is actually a doomsday cult. And they are very effective with this teaching (for them G-d the mother is a korean lady) but I'm trying to see how to prove that their teaching is not that correct. The problem is that they have a comeback for everything.

Comment: OK, this cult is just creepy. Good luck in your disproving of them! But I think the better option would be to ignore them, and not confront them.

Answer (score 7):

It is important to keep in mind that the effectively universal opinion<sup>1</sup> in Orthodox Judaism is that Gd takes no image. So when Gd is described as anthropomorphic in any Jewish literature, in order to understand that description, we must think in an abstract, metaphorical way.

This view is codified explicitly in Maimonides' 13 Principles of faith, which he outlines in his commentary on the mishnah ,(**Sanh. 10:1**). It is based on verses in the Bible, **Deuteronomy 4:15**, to name one. This stance is also evident from Tanaaic times, through [Onkelos the Convert's](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=megilah&daf=3a&go=Go) translation of the bible into aramaic, where he goes out of his way to describe human-like attributes of Gd in conceptual ways, (one of many, many examples can be seen in **Genesis 29:32**).

Equally important is the concept of the oneness of Gd, discussed by Maimonides in the same place, and based on **Deuteronomy 6:4**. Maimonides puts it best:

*"... not like one in a pair and not like one in a species and not like a single man that splits in to many individuals and not like one simple body that can be split up endlessly, rather He... is one in oneness, that there is none like it in oneness..."*

**So Gd having two literal images, or being of two genders, or having gender at all, or being two things contradicts fundamental Jewish belief.**

**All of that being said**, we do see both genders relating to Gd. Generally, Gd is referred to as a male, whether He is referred to with the name Elokim, (**Gen. 1:27**), the ineffable name, (**Gen 2:5**), or the name of Adonut, (**Gen. 18:30**).

The only female word we find in relation to Gd is the *Shechina*, the dwelling or resting [of G-d's presence]. This name is alluded to in **Ex. 25:8**, and mentioned explicitly many times throughout rabbinic literature, for example by Onkelos in **Gen 9:27**, in [Megillah 29a](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=megilah&daf=29a&go=Go), or [Bava Basra 58b](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=bava_basra&daf=58a&go=Go). The *Shechina* is even referred to metaphorically as a niddah, a woman who is impure from her menses, in the extremely esoteric passage of קם רבי שמעון Which is from the Tikkunei Zohar, (see Artscroll Yom Kippur Machzor Hayim Yehezkel p. 56).

One way of understanding gender relating Gd is through the roles of men and women, seen most clearly and simply through the act of procreation. The male acts upon the female, who receives that action and nurtures it, creating new life.

Based on the above metaphor, one can easily see Gd as a male, for everything comes from Him, and He controls the world and acts upon it.

I have come across two understandings of the female role of the Shechina. The first is alluded to in **Exodus 25:8**, *"And they shall make for Me a holy place, and I shall dwell amongst them"*. Notice that Gd dwells amongst us only after we make a holy place for Him. In order to have a realization and appreciation of Gd's presence in our lives and from our perspective we must preform an action which He responds to, cultivating it into a human realization of His Presence, as the female cultivates the actions of the male.

The second understanding is based on the final *'Heh'* in the ineffable four letter Name, (I think I saw this in *Jewish Meditation*, written by Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan, z"l). Basically, the letters of the name describe Gd's conveying effects of His will from Himself unto us. The final *Heh*, the *Shechinah* represents His receiving His presence unto us, allowing us to be aware of and recognize Him. In accepting His presence from Himself unto us, His Shechina playing the role of the female in the metaphor, (***Bear in mind the Oneness Principle***).

---

<sup>1. I asked [Rav Ahron Lopiansky](http://www.aish.com/authors/48865682.html) about [Corporealist Rishonim](http://www.hashkafacircle.com/journal/R3_DS_Taku.pdf). He said that there are only two that we know of who even mention it as a possibility. One is the Ravad, who mentions corporealism as a mistake that some made. The other is Rav Moshe Taku, who discusses corporealism, but whose extant work is too fragmented to surmise any clear opinion or stance from. First and foremost it is a polemic against rationalism, esotericism, and any other processes of analysis that he felt "watered down" the simple meaning of the Bible and the Sages. Any mention of corporealism would then just be an argumentative counter claim to show the holes in such claims.</sup>

Comment: "The only female word we find attributed to Gd is the title Shechina" The shekhina is not God. God is described as masculine. The shekhina is a created entity.

Comment: @mevaqesh how bout now?

Comment: Better. But you still have basically no sources that directly address the shekhina's connection to God that would allow us to determine whether it is even relevant to the question.

Comment: Re your point that the Shechinah is referred to as feminine is simply because Shechinah is a feminine word. The reason HaShem is usually referred to as masculine is because that is the "default" gender in Hebrew.

Comment: @mevaqesh source that the Shechina is a created entity please!

Comment: @mevaqesh whether the shechina is God or not is an argument amongst. Saadia Gaon indeed classifies it as kavod nivra. The Ramban disagrees and insists that it is not a created entity.